# DC.js computing mean according to dimension

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
MONTH    CAT   VAL
may      A     1.0
may      B     3.2
may      C     4.6
jun      A     2.7
jun      B     4.2
jun      C     5.8
jul      A     4.1
jul      B     9.2
jul      C     13.0
```

I've been able to create a chart in DC.js that **shows the sum of VAL according to the CAT variable**, with this code:

```
let chart = dc.barChart('#chart');

let ndx = crossfilter(data);

let catDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.cat;});
let catGroup = catDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return +d.val;}); 

chart
    .dimension(catDim)
    .group(catGroup)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(catDim))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticY(true)
```

My problem is that instead of the sum, I would like to show in the grafic the **average of VAL per MONTH for each CAT**  (MONTH can be filtered in another graph).

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Agree with Xavier's answer; see [the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ) and [annotated stock example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) for sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of using crossfilter to "just" keep track of the sum, use a custom reduce that tracks both the sum and the number of items, and add a valueAccessor to return x.value.sum/x.value.qty

I would suggest you to use [reductio](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio) to handle the custom reduce, check the examples, you have one for the average.